# Django - Calculate Average Score Using Multiple JOINs

Tags: python, django

I am trying to calculate the average score for each student using Django ORM.
Here are my models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    birth_date = models.DateField()


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    units = models.IntegerField()


class StudentScore(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    score = models.FloatField()
```

For each student, the average score is calculated as:
sum(score * course_units) / sum(course_units)

I need to get the student ID vs. average score as output.

Here is the equivalent SQL query (assuming the Django app name is 'dummy'):

```
select ss.student_id, sum(ss.score * c.units) / sum(c.units) 
from dummy_studentscore ss
join dummy_student s on s.id = ss.student_id
join dummy_course c on c.id = ss.course_id
group by ss.student_id
```

How can I achieve the same using Django ORM API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out:

```
    query = StudentScore.objects.values('student') \
        .annotate(result=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('score') * F('course__units')) / Sum('course__units'), 
                                           output_field=models.FloatField()))
```